# Does this test make proper use of AutoFixture and Moq?

Tags: mocking, moq, autofixture

Does this test make proper use of AutoFixture and Moq? Is it written as concisely as possible?  The test fails, as expected, and passes after writing the correct implementation.

```cs
[Fact]
public void CustomerPropertyIsCorrect()
{
    var fixture = new AutoMoqFixture();

    var expected = fixture.Create<CardHolderCustomer>();
    var builderMock = fixture
        .Freeze<Mock<ICustomerAdapter>>()
        .Setup(x => x.BuildCustomer()).Returns(expected);

    var sut = fixture.Create<CardHolderViewModel>();
    var actual = sut.Customer;

    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's looking good! However, **you can also use it [declaratively](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheoriesWithAutoFixture.aspx)** with the xUnit.net [extension](http://nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit/).

Assuming that the types used in the test are defined as:

```cs
public class CardHolderCustomer
{
}

public interface ICustomerAdapter
{
    CardHolderCustomer BuildCustomer();
}

public class CardHolderViewModel
{
    private readonly ICustomerAdapter adapter;

    public CardHolderViewModel(ICustomerAdapter adapter)
    {
        if (adapter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("adapter");
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    public CardHolderCustomer Customer
    {
        get
        {
            return this.adapter.BuildCustomer();
        }
    }
}
```

**The original test can be written as**:

```cs
[Theory, DomainTestConventions]
public void CustomerPropertyIsCorrect2(
    CardHolderCustomer expected,
    [Frozen]Mock<ICustomerAdapter> builderStub,
    CardHolderViewModel sut)
{
    builderStub
        .Setup(x => x.BuildCustomer())
        .Returns(expected);

    var actual = sut.Customer;

    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

The `DomainTestConventionsAttribute` is defined as:

```cs
internal class DomainTestConventionsAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    internal DomainTestConventionsAttribute()
        :base(new Fixture().Customize(new DomainTestConventions()))
    {
    }
}
```

The `DomainTestConventions` is defined as:

```cs
internal class DomainTestConventions : CompositeCustomization
{
    internal DomainTestConventions()
        :base(new AutoMoqCustomization())
    {
    }
}
```

***Note that `DomainTestConventions` derives from `CompositeCustomization` which basically means that you can create more Customizations and add them as parameters to the base constructor.***

You may also read:

- [The order of AutoFixture Customizations matter](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/31/TheorderofAutoFixtureCustomizationsmatter/)
- [AutoData Theories with AutoFixture](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture/)
- [Keep your unit tests DRY with AutoFixture Customizations](http://megakemp.com/2011/12/15/keep-your-unit-tests-dry-with-autofixture-customizations/)
- [AutoFixture, xUnit.net, and Auto Mocking](http://nikosbaxevanis.com/2012/07/31/autofixture-xunit-net-and-auto-mocking/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly the feedback I was looking for.

Comment: I just have to add... the fact you reproduced my code blind proves better than any agile book ever could that tests are the primary source of documentation for code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is concise and readable. But I question the *value* of this kind of test.

Your test is named **CustomerPropertyIsCorrect**, so I assume this is what you want to test. Since you instruct the **BuildCustomer** method of your **ICustomerAdapter** to return the frozen instance created earlier, and since the view model code will use this code when run in xUnit, yes, the frozen object will indeed be returned.

Now, I'm not all-in the TDD camp (yet) so this may just be me, not "getting" TDD. But as far as I can see, this test will verify that the view model has some **CardHolderCustomer** instance in its Customer property - but not necessarily the "correct" one. Where's the value in that?